# Move users to other OU based on emailaddresses in CSV

Tags: powershell

I have a `CSV` file with emailaddresses ( also known in AD ). I would like to move the users to a different OU. My CSV looks like :

```
mail
user@company.com
user2@company.com
```

Anyone a idea how to get this fixed ?

I've tried the following:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-CSV <CSV-file>.csv | % { 
  Get-ADUser $_.mail | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "ou=<Destination OU>,dc=<DOMAIN>,dc=<DC>" -whatif 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried _anything_?

Comment: Maybe try reading the documentation, you might find [Move-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/)

Comment: Yes @MathiasR.Jessen I did try something : 

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-CSV <CSV-file>.csv | % { Get-ADUser $_.mail | Move-ADObject -TargetPath "ou=<Destination OU>,dc=<DOMAIN>,dc=<DC>" -whatif }

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Import-CSV <CSV-file>.csv | Foreach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {(mail -eq "$($_.mail)")} -Properties DistinguishedName 
    Move-ADObject -Identity $user.DistinguishedName -TargetPath "ou=<Destination OU>,dc=<DOMAIN>,dc=<DC>" -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: This is the result : </br>
<pre><code> Move-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I don't have ActiveDirectory module at the monent.. Try `$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {(mail -eq "$($_.mail)")}`

Comment: Hi Theo, have the same error. I think it also the same defeinition as in the previous code.